# How to label a factor var using another var

Tags: r

I have a df like below, I would like to build a new factor var `ID2` which level =unique(.ID) which arranged by `Order` , but label = corresponding `Type`. What should I do in order to get this?

[image]

```
df<- structure(list(Order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 5), ID = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A2", "A5"), Type = c("Art", 
"Math", "Art", "ELA", "Math", "Math", "ELA", "Math", "Math"), 
    score = c(91, 85, NA, 77, NA, 22, NA, 89, 54)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df %>% arrange(Order) %>% mutate(ID2= factor(ID,
levels= unique(.$ID),
labels=...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a data frame with the `distinct` `ID` and `Type` data as the source for `levels` and `labels`.

```r
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  arrange(Order) %>%
  mutate(ID2 = factor(ID,
                      levels = distinct(df, ID, Type)$ID,
                      labels = distinct(df, ID, Type)$Type))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 5
#>   Order ID    Type  score ID2  
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <fct>
#> 1     1 A1    Art      91 Art  
#> 2     2 A2    Math     85 Math 
#> 3     2 A2    Math     89 Math 
#> 4     3 A3    Art      NA Art  
#> 5     4 A4    ELA      77 ELA  
#> 6     5 A5    Math     NA Math 
#> 7     5 A5    Math     54 Math 
#> 8     6 A6    Math     22 Math 
#> 9     7 A7    ELA      NA ELA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>